# jquery UI tooltip - what 'my' and 'at' mean? Why call tooltip() twice?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

In the position property, there are two options : "my" and "at". 
I don't understand how to configure the position of the popup bubble through these options. 
What do they mean?

In order to figure out these options clearly, I found an example on-line, but still cannot figure out. 
For example, when the bubble is shown on the left of the input area, but the value of "my" is 'right center', why is that?

Why call tooltip() twice? One tooltip with arguements is called within on(), and another one without arguements is on outside the on() trigger? 
Why is that?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/kyBwU/

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    var className = $(this).val();
    var position;
    switch (className) {
        case 'top':
            position = { my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top-10' };
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            position = { my: 'center top', at: 'center bottom+10' };
            break;
        case 'left':
            position = { my: 'right center', at: 'left-10 center' };
            break;
        case 'right':
            position = { my: 'left center', at: 'right+10 center' };
            break;
    }
    position.collision = 'none';

    $('input[type="text"]').tooltip('option', 'position', position);
    $('input[type="text"]').tooltip('option', 'tooltipClass', className);
});

$('#options').buttonset();
$('input[type="text"]').tooltip();
$('input[value="right"]').trigger('change');
```

And I tried to create my own, somehow, the last input text field is always preselected. 
It is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/sks358zo/18/

Comment: Its basically like reading a sentence. Move "my" location "at" the location "of" another object

Comment: "Place my (relative-coordinate) at (the relative-coordinate of the originator)"

Comment: By reading the [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) I think it is more like 'my' object has an tooltip 'at' whatever location.

Comment: And I tried to create my own, somehow, the last input text field is always preselected. 
It is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/sks358zo/18/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's what we have [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) for.

> The jQuery UI .position() method allows you to position an element relative to the window, document, another element, or the cursor/mouse, without worrying about offset parents.

**my (default: "center") Type: String**

> Defines which position on the
>   element being positioned to align with the target element: "horizontal
>   vertical" alignment. A single value such as "right" will be normalized
>   to "right center", "top" will be normalized to "center top" (following
>   CSS convention). Acceptable horizontal values: "left", "center",
>   "right". Acceptable vertical values: "top", "center", "bottom".
>   Example: "left top" or "center center". Each dimension can also
>   contain offsets, in pixels or percent, e.g., "right+10 top-25%".
>   Percentage offsets are relative to the element being positioned.

**at (default: "center") Type: String**

> Defines which position on the target
>   element to align the positioned element against: "horizontal vertical"
>   alignment. See the my option for full details on possible values.
>   Percentage offsets are relative to the target element.

Comment: Sorry, I feel like this comment is unhelpful and unnecessarily snarky. I think it's pretty clear the poster has read the documentation, especially since he's referencing the properties defined in the documentation. I have always thought that jQuery's tooltip positioning is not very intuitive and not explained well in the documentation.

Comment: @deaddancer  Then why did OP mark this as the correct answer?  Please don't speak for other people.